# iMacros - create batch file to start javascript file in existing browser window

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file, firefox, imacros

I'm trying to create a batch file to start a .js file (tom.js) on imacros (firefox browser) at a specific time. 
The most simple solution seams to be:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\> start firefox.exe imacros://run/?m=TOM.js
```

Then I will use windows task scheduler to run the .bat file at a specific time..

Problem: This line `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\
start firefox.exe` actually opens a new window of firefox, then runs the tom.js file.
I would like the .bat file to run tom.js file on the ALREADY OPEN firefox browser instead to open a new window of firefox each time. The reason is that i have a few sites in a few tabs already opened and logged in, it would be much more simple if the command to run the `.js` file does that in one of the already opened tabs (tab 1 ideally).

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: I am almost 100% sure this is impossible with only batch... I have looked around and found [this](http://superuser.com/questions/601850/open-a-url-file-in-a-new-tab-of-existing-ie-window-from-command-line) on SuperUser and tried to adapt, but I am not familiar with powershell and did not come any further. My idea would be to echo the content into a powershell file, execute it, and delete it again from the batch-file. Maybe this can help in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just bypass the '.bat' approach in the following way:

```
var startTime = "2017-01-24T11:55:00";
var secWait = parseInt((new Date(startTime) - new Date()) / 1000);
secWait = Math.max(0, secWait);
iimPlayCode("WAIT SECONDS=" + secWait);
window.location.href = "imacros://run/?m=TOM.js";
```

In addition, it's possible to make this code as 'iim'-macro. (Sometimes more preferable.)